# Adding item to knock out view model , is not updating the view

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a ViewModel which I am binding to view list item.

```
var MyViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.addItems = function(vm) {
        vm.inventoryItems.push('New Item');
    }
};

var myVM= new MyViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(myVM);
```

The view model has a property called `inventoryItems` (which is from a service).

I am bidning that to view using ,

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:inventoryItems">
    <li>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: $data" />
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="text-right">
    <a data-bind="click: $parent.addItems">+ Add more</a>
</div>
```

Now, the items that are already in the collection , `inventoryItems` are getting rendered fine.

When I am adding a new item using, I can see the items being added via console, but the view is not getting updated!

```
self.addItems = function(vm) {
            vm.inventoryItems.push('New Item');
        }
```

Comment: Is `vm.inventoryItems` a `ko.observableArray` ?

Comment: @JonathanTwite, I am just getting that array from service. So I guess, it's not observable. How do I make that observable?

Comment: Is "service" another viewmodel? or is it a plain object that retrieves the data?  If you are wanting to display the items in `inventoryItems`, they should really be a parameter on your ViewModel.  The ViewModel is the data and logic you wish to show onscreen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code snippet will make your inventoryItems observable

```
    var MyViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.inventoryItems = ko.observableArray();

    self.addItems = function (vm) {
        vm.inventories.push('New Item');
        self.inventoryItems(vm.inventories);
      }
  };
var myVM = new MyViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(myVM);
```